# Select not starting at the specified option value

Tags: php, html, html-select

I am attempting to create an empty option that starts as "selected" so that I can run a check to make sure an option was chosen from the drop down menu.  However, for some reason the option I marked as selected doesn't start off selected from the drop down.  Anybody have an idea as to why?

```
<select name="PCP" id="PCP">
  <option value="" selected="selected"></option>
    <?php 
$sql_status = "SELECT * FROM providers WHERE PCP = 'Y'";

$rs_status = mysql_query($sql_status);
while($row_status = mysql_fetch_array($rs_status))
{
echo "<option value=\"".$row_status['PROVID']."\">".$row_status['FULLNAME']."\n  ";
}
?>
</select>
```

Comment: you missed `</option>`?

Comment: I don't believe it's necessary, although I have tried it both ways without any success.

Comment: can you explain more this statement: `doesn't start off selected from the drop down`

Comment: @Akam In a drop down, there is a value that starts off filled in/visible.  For example, this page has "butter" as the beginning value in it's first drop down.  http://www.echoecho.com/htmlforms11.htm  The option that I would like to be initially selected isn't selected as I believe it should be.

Answer (score 4):

Don't you want to close your `<option>` with `</option>` like following?

```
echo "<option value=\"".$row_status['PROVID']."\">".$row_status['FULLNAME']."</option>";
```

Update:

Since PHP will evaluate variables within double quotes, you could simplify the above statement as follows:

```
echo "<option value='$row_status['PROVID']'>$row_status['FULLNAME']</option>";
```

Comment: do you still use `"<option value=\""` instead of `'<option value="'`

Comment: @Akam, my intention here is to answer OP's question and I do not see any problems using `\""`, please explain the flaw in using `"<option value=\""`.

Comment: yes, but while answering we must provide exactly correct method and approach regardless of what OP asking or using, thanks for taking my note

Comment: @Akam, please see my update above.  Do you still use `'<option value="'` instead of my updated answer?

Comment: It is valid HTML to have unclosed `option` tags. The closing tag is optional. See [tag omission](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/option).

Comment: @Akam, I agree with you that we should come up with best solution for the question.  The first and foremost being question at hand.  Better solution can be proposed with edits if required.  I do not see any problems with using `\""` which is perfectly valid.

Comment: good, but concatenation is better like this: `echo '<option value="'.$row_status['PROVID'].'">'.$row_status['FULLNAME'].'</option>';`

Comment: @FabrícioMatté, browsers might be very forgiving, but I don't think we should consider that to be valid.  Also the use of `\n` instead of closing tag is not valid, is it?

Comment: @vinodadhikary It **is valid** per W3C spec. Updated previous comment with reference FYI.

Comment: @FabrícioMatté, Please read the `Tag Omission` part in the highlighted box.  "The end tag is optional if this element is immediately followed by another <option> element or an <optgroup>, or if the parent element has no more content."

Comment: @vinodadhikary ... and your point is? OP is outputting `<option>` after `<option>` until the `</select>`.

Comment: @vinodadhikary a line break, sure. That counts as collapsed white space inside the option's text content.

Comment: @FabrícioMatté, alright you got me :).  Still gonna try this out in other browsers though :) +1 for your comment in enlightening me.

Comment: @vinodadhikary No problem. `=]` I agree that omitting the closing tag in this case is terrifically ugly, but it is still valid. For anyone that wants to check with their own eyes, take [this bin](http://jsbin.com/osukig/3/edit)'s HTML and throw in the [w3c validator](http://validator.w3.org).

Comment: Thanks for the response, although this doesn't provide a fix for the issue.  I'm really confused because I've checked this code so many times and I can't seem to find anything wrong with it.  Also, thanks for the code simplification.  It makes it much more readable.

Comment: @CrashLanding, wanted to ask you if your query is working.  Do you see the generated options?

Comment: @vinodadhikary I do see the options pulled from mySQL.  It just doesn't have the option selected that I would like to have selected when the page is loaded.